# Not able to configure virtual directory in iis

Tags: php, wordpress, iis

I have instlled wordpress in server and i've created virtual directories.In server it is working fine.
Here is my problem,i want to create virtual directories in wordpress in windows system with IIS.But i'm not able to do that.When i'm trying to access that virtual directory i'm getting error message like below:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

I did same thing in IIS what i have done in server.
Pls help me out.